# How to create a window through one layer into another layer

Tags: ios, xcode, image, window, layer

I'm looking for some direction to help achieve a specific capability in my app.

It's a little hard to explain, but here goes. Although I'm visualizing my goal using a multi-layer metaphor (a la Photoshop), this is just to explain my vision - I realize that may not be reasonable in practice.

I envision 3 "layers"

1. A bottom layer that contains an image
2. Another layer on top - say a 50% gray - but at reduced opacity so the original layer is still visible but de-emphasized.
3. Then two square objects  on the top layer, each acting as a "window" through the gray layer, down to the original layer and so -
   through these windows, you get to see part of the original image at
   full opacity.

Finally, need to be able to drag each window around the screen with a finger, to independently reposition each one.

Extra credit would be if each window could be adjusted in size (not shape - still square) ideally using a finger gesture of some kind.

I'm not looking for code (although I wouldn't object). I'm looking for an approach to doing this in Objective-C that ideally doesn't require me digging into advanced topics such as some of the graphics frameworks.

Thanks!
Tony.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a rough outline of what I would try.

I would use 2 view (not layers). The bottom most view would be the image view.

The top view would be a custom view. This custom view would have two other views as subviews. These two subviews would represent the two "holes". Setup both subviews with their own gesture recognizers to handle panning and zooming. Give both of the subviews (and the container view) a clear background and possibly a border. The main view of this custom view would need to have its `drawRect:` method implemented. The implementation would draw the partially transparent grey background. It would use the position and size of the two subviews to setup clipping regions before drawing the grey color.

Every time the 2 subviews are sized or moved you would need to call `setNeedsDisplay` on the container view so the `drawRect:` method is called to refresh the grey background with the holes.

Comment: @rmaddy-thanks.
In storyboard, I have a UIImageView containing 2 subviews.

Starting one at a time, I've made Subview1 a UIGestureRecognizerDelegate and added a pan gesture recognizer with associated selector. However, I suppose I'm used to working at the UIViewController level, where instance methods such as viewDidLoad would allow me to add my gesture setup code. In the Subview, all I have by default is initWithFrame, but that's not firing. I discovered initWithCoder - that *is* triggered, but putting my gesture code there results in an uncaught exception.

Any guidance appreciated.

Comment: OK, I have both subviews responding to gestures. I'm stuck now with how to create the clipping regions in the drawRect: method of the Container view. ANy guidance appreciate. FYI, my view hierarchy consists of: UIViewController containing UIView containing Background Image UIImageView plus Container UIView containing SubView1 and Subview 2 UIImageViews.

Comment: Finally got it working after much playing around. Eventually used elements of your method maddy. Thanks also to @Bergasms for his suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I would rearrange it. instead, have a flat image of the background image with the 50% grey stamped onto it at the bottom. Then, the two squares that you have, are actually UIImageViews with the background image set to a fixed location, and the image views clip that image to their bounds. As you move the two imageviews around, you just translate the origin of the image.

Sorry, this is kind of hard to explain what I am thinking. I should try drawing it out.

Comment: Hi Bergasms - thanks for the suggestion. I'm not having much luck with  the other suggestion, so would be grateful if you could elaborate further on yours?

Comment: Sure, ill put together something to hopefully help you in a mo.

Comment: Hi Bergasms. Sorry to bug. Any luck?

Comment: Sorry, totally spaced there. So, how I would arrange it is as follows. Your bottom layer consists of the image, with the 50% opacity applied to it in some fashion. This sits at the bottom and you don't need to do anything else to it. Now, the two views that you can move around both have a uiimageview as a subview, and this uiimageview contains your base image, the movable views clip their subviews to bounds. The movable views frame is the same as the base view, however the bounds for the movable view represents your "window". the movement using touches should be used to move the bounds around.

Comment: So what this gives you in effect is the base image is only shown in your "windows" where the bounds are located, and the rest of the "windows" view will be transparent. Please note this is only one way. Another way is to have the opacity drawn as a CALayer. the "Windows" are transparent views that can be moved with touches, and the calayer uses those views to draw transparent rectangles over the opcaity it draws. this is another way.